# WPF Databound Property Loosing value

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, mvvm, binding

Hi I have a viewmodel where i can track the value of a certain item in the constructor. I am opening a dialog window using the MVVM model.

example

```
private int _myField;
public ClassName(int MyProperty)
{
  _myField = MyProperty;
}

public int MyIntProperty
{
   get{ return _myField;}
   set { _myField = value;}
}
```

this is all perfect obviously. 
but as soon as the window opens the value in the viewmodel changes. 
lets say the _myField goes from 1 to 8 with out any interaction. i've walked through the code and there are no other interactions with the field.

also not in the code sample is the bound property.

anyone every came accross this before. it has me stumped.

**Edit:** included missing property from example

Comment: are you binding to `_myField`? generally in WPF you bind to a property. In addition, that will allow you to set a breakpoint on the property getter/setter and figure out why the value is changing

Comment: yeah. "also not in the code sample is the bound property." , at the moment i have a hack to resolve it but its not a very clean solution.

Comment: You say "Let's say the _myField goes from 1 to 8" - is that a genuine example?  Have you put a breakpoint in the property setter to see where it's being called from?  (It *must* be called from somewhere...)  And if you include the binding to the property in your question, we might find an answer there.

Answer (score 1):

You should either:

1) Implement INotifyPropertyChanged on ClassName.  This will allow you to raise the PropertyChanged event when you change MyIntProperty.  WPF will listen to this event and update the UI accordingly.

or

2) Make ClassName inherit from DependancyObject and MyIntProperty a dependency property.  This will take care of everything for you.